# Factorize Spark column

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Is it possible to factorize a Spark dataframe column? With factorizing I mean creating a mapping of each unique value in the column to the same ID.

Example, the original dataframe:

```
+----------+----------------+--------------------+
|      col1|            col2|                col3|
+----------+----------------+--------------------+
|1473490929|4060600988513370|                   A|
|1473492972|4060600988513370|                   A|
|1473509764|4060600988513370|                   B|
|1473513432|4060600988513370|                   C|
|1473513432|4060600988513370|                   A|
+----------+----------------+--------------------+
```

to the factorized version:

```
+----------+----------------+--------------------+
|      col1|            col2|                col3|
+----------+----------------+--------------------+
|1473490929|4060600988513370|                   0|
|1473492972|4060600988513370|                   0|
|1473509764|4060600988513370|                   1|
|1473513432|4060600988513370|                   2|
|1473513432|4060600988513370|                   0|
+----------+----------------+--------------------+
```

In scala itself it would be fairly simple, but since Spark distributes it's dataframes over nodes I'm not sure how to keep a mapping from `A->0, B->1, C->2`.

Also, assume the dataframe is pretty big (gigabytes), which means loading one entire column into the memory of a single machine might not be possible.

Can it be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `StringIndexer` to encode letters into indices:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.StringIndexer

val indexer = new StringIndexer()
  .setInputCol("col3")
  .setOutputCol("col3Index")

val indexed = indexer.fit(df).transform(df)
indexed.show()

+----------+----------------+----+---------+
|      col1|            col2|col3|col3Index|
+----------+----------------+----+---------+
|1473490929|4060600988513370|   A|      0.0|
|1473492972|4060600988513370|   A|      0.0|
|1473509764|4060600988513370|   B|      1.0|
|1473513432|4060600988513370|   C|      2.0|
|1473513432|4060600988513370|   A|      0.0|
+----------+----------------+----+---------+
```

**Data:**

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
              (1473490929, "4060600988513370", "A"),
              (1473492972, "4060600988513370", "A"),  
              (1473509764, "4060600988513370", "B"),
              (1473513432, "4060600988513370", "C"),
              (1473513432, "4060600988513370", "A"))).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")
```

Comment: Perfect, works like a charm! Completely forgot about spark-mllib.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an user defined function.

First you create the mapping you need:

```
val updateFunction = udf {(x: String) =>
  x match {
    case "A" => 0
    case "B" => 1
    case "C" => 2
    case _ => 3
  }
}
```

And now you only have to apply it to your `DataFrame`:

```
df.withColumn("col3", updateFunction(df.col("col3")))
```

Comment: Imagine having 30+ values :). It would be a hell to maintain this.

Comment: The function should be a bit better than this one. It was just an example ;).

Comment: I know, but still it would be really difficult to maintain if all the values are manually specified.