# How to use Spark ML ALS algorithm?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to use ALS in spark ML to predict starts. My data structure like that

```
        business_id|             user_id|          stars|
        +--------------------+--------------------+-----+
        |5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANh...|PUFPaY9KxDAcGqfso...|    4|
        |5UmKMjUEUNdYWqANh...|Iu6AxdBYGR4A0wspR...|    5|
        |UsFtqoBl7naz8AVUB...|uK8tzraOp4M5u3uYr...|    5|
        |cE27W9VPgO88Qxe4o...|fhNxoMwwTipzjO8A9...|    3|
```

The ALS requires user_id and item_id are int. I try to transform string to 
hashcode,it does't work.

```
        +-----------+-----------+-----+
        |    user_id|business_id|stars|
        +-----------+-----------+-----+
        |-1483211020| -939110651|  4.0|
        |-1483211020| 1184210788|  4.0|
        |-1941267903|  304488013|  5.0|
        | 2081449993|-1999999294|  3.0|
        | 2081449993|-1809940661|  4.0|
        | 1089298712|  -84655838|  5.0|

        Root-mean-square error = NaN
```

How to transform id to continue Int using scala?

Comment: you can use [StringIndexer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39743028/factorize-spark-column/)

Comment: Wow, it is useful!!!

Comment: Yes, I think so :)

Comment: Can you look at this problem? [ASL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43544815/why-spark-ml-als-algorithm-print-rmse-nan)