# Why Spark ML ALS algorithm print RMSE = NaN?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning

I use ALS to predict rating, this is my code:

```
val als = new ALS()
  .setMaxIter(5)
  .setRegParam(0.01)
  .setUserCol("user_id")
  .setItemCol("business_id")
  .setRatingCol("stars")
val model = als.fit(training)

// Evaluate the model by computing the RMSE on the test data
val predictions = model.transform(testing)
predictions.sort("user_id").show(1000)
val evaluator = new RegressionEvaluator()
  .setMetricName("rmse")
  .setLabelCol("stars")
  .setPredictionCol("prediction")
val rmse = evaluator.evaluate(predictions)
println(s"Root-mean-square error = $rmse")
```

But get some negative scores and RMSE is Nan:

```
+-------+-----------+---------+------------+
|user_id|business_id|    stars|  prediction|
+-------+-----------+---------+------------+
|      0|       2175|      4.0|   4.0388923|
|      0|       5753|      3.0|   2.6875196|
|      0|       9199|      4.0|   4.1753435|
|      0|      16416|      2.0|   -2.710618|
|      0|       6063|      3.0|         NaN|
|      0|      23076|      2.0|  -0.8930751|

Root-mean-square error = NaN
```

How to get a good result?

Comment: Maybe `predictions.where("prediction != 'NaN'"))` works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Negative values don't matter as RMSE squares the values first. Probably you have empty prediction values. You could drop them:

```
predictions.na().drop(["prediction"])
```

Although, that can be a bit misleading, alternatively you could fill those values with your lowest/highest/average rating.

I'd also recommend to round `x < min_rating` and `x > max_rating` to the lowest/highest ratings, which would improve your RMSE.

EDIT:

Some extra info here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-14489

Comment: I use `predictions.na.drop()`, but sill get NaN.

Comment: Can you check your data if you have any nulls or NAs?

Comment: I have checked my result, it still contian "NaN".

Comment: It would be helpful if you could update your question. Which columns? Is that a null or a NaN? etc. It's hard to answer a question that is not reproducible.

Comment: I use `spark.sql("select * from result where prediction != 'NaN'")` to filter the result. It works!

Answer (score 5):

Since Spark version 2.2.0 you can set the `coldStartStrategy` parameter to `drop` in order to drop any rows in the DataFrame of predictions that contain NaN values. The evaluation metric will then be computed over the non-NaN data and will be valid.

```
model.setColdStartStrategy("drop");
```

Answer (score 1):

A small correction will solve this issue:

prediction.na.drop()